# How to use Range stored in a Variant variable to copy and paste?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to take a range of cells like:

David Scott Employee

and copy/paste on another sheet. It works when I use explicit "ActiveSheet.Range" but not when calling a variable with the range stored in it.

```vb
Sub zUpdateTable()
    Dim wsCurrent As Worksheet: Set wsCurrent = Sheets("GlobalUpdate")
    Dim wsTable As Worksheet: Set wsTable = Sheets("Table")
    Dim fromValue As Variant
    Dim toValue As Variant
    
    fromAddress1 = wsCurrent.Range("U77")
    toAddress1 = wsCurrent.Range("U86")
    fromValue = wsCurrent.Range("U66:W66")
    toValue = wsCurrent.Range("U68:W68")
    
    fromValue.copy
    wsTable.Range(wsCurrent.Range("S86")).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    
End Sub
```

When I get to:

```
fromValue.copy
```

I get

> Run-Time error '424': Object Required

Comment: Try `Set fromValue = wsCurrent.Range("U66:W66")` instead of `fromValue = wsCurrent.Range("U66:W66")`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only pasting the values try something like this:

```vb
Sub zUpdateTable()
  Dim wsCurrent As Worksheet: Set wsCurrent = Sheets("GlobalUpdate")
  Dim wsTable As Worksheet: Set wsTable = Sheets("Table")
  Dim sDestAddress As String
  
  sDestAddress = wsCurrent.Range("S86")
  With wsCurrent.Range("U66:W66")
    wsTable.Range(sDestAddress).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value2 = .Value2
  End With
End Sub
```

**(Not Tested)**